# How to rename a uploaded pdf via PHP. With this specific code

Tags: php, pdf

How can I use the code below and rename the pdf before moving the file to a directory?

```
<?php
session_start();

$full = $_SESSION['full'];

mkdir('pictures/'.$full.'_uploads', 0777, true);
chmod('pictures', 0777);
chmod('pictures/'.$full.'_uploads', 0777);


$target_dir = 'pictures/'.$full.'_uploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file )) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I prefer name the file a specific name, not a random name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your desired name after target dir in targe filename like below. And rest is the same of your code.

```
$target_file = $target_dir ."myfavoritename.pdf";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file )) {
```

Comment: wow I did that earlier but forgot to take off the ) at the end. #facepalm

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Thanks mate! Edited!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) function

> rename — Renames a file or directory

```
rename ("/folder/file.ext", "/folder/newfile.ext");
```

Though @disha's approach is better.

Comment: Thanks, yours is not bad! :)

Comment: looks more like an comment

Comment: @NullPoiиteя - You mean I should have commented that? It appeared more like an alternative answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your target file variable :

```
$target_file = $target_dir.mktime(date("h"),date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("y")).basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

I have renamed the current pdf name with current time. You can use it accordingly.